# php ob_implicit_flush not working without sleep

Tags: php, ajax

I want to send pretty rapid updates to my ajax script, so I'm echoing some status statements from my PHP script.

Problem is, if PHP runs too quickly and pumps out too many status updates fast, the ajax script often gets the information inconsistently and thinks the JSON is formatted incorrectly.

This is something that I thought should work, but it does not:

```
ob_implicit_flush(true);
ob_end_flush();

for($i = 0; $i < 20; $i++){
    sendMsg($i);
}

function sendMsg($msg){
    echo json_encode(array('msg' => $msg));
}
```

The JS gets the message in chunks of output, rather than each individual piece as I'd expect.  And it's rather inconsistent in terms of how much is sent back to JS each time I run the script.

This is an example output I'm getting.  I expect 20 messages, but I get 2 return messages from PHP:

```
{"msg":0}
{"msg":1}{"msg":2}{"msg":3}{"msg":4}{"msg":5}{"msg":6}{"msg":7}{"msg":8}{"msg":9}{"msg":10}{"msg":11}{"msg":12}{"msg":13}{"msg":14}{"msg":15}{"msg":16}{"msg":17}{"msg":18}{"msg":19}
```

If I add `sleep(1)` to the for-loop it works fine, but that's slowing things down unnecessarily just to have nice output.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try `while(@ob_end_flush());`

Comment: @CharlotteDunois where would I put that statement?  Sorry if it's obvious ;)

Comment: Instead of `ob_end_flush();`

Comment: Tried that.  Top two lines of the script are now:
`ob_implicit_flush(true);`
`while(@ob_end_flush());`

Same issue.

Comment: Does adding `flush(); ob_flush();` into the loop after `echo` help?

Comment: No.  `flush()` does nothing, which `ob_flush()` throws an error saying there is no buffer to flush.  I tried removing `ob_implicit_flush(true)` to no avail as well.

I am bad at this buffer thing ;)